# Populating UserForm Data to an Excel Table

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a UserForm as shown by the image. The data from this has to be populated to an excel table named 'Database'. I have copied various VBA Codes from the internet to populate the table but all in vain. The code is as follows:

```
Sub ResetItem()    ' The reset button coding

    Sub Submit_Data()

    Dim iRow As Long

    If adminpanel.txtRowNumber.Value = "" Then

        iRow = student.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    Else

        iRow = adminpanel.txtRowNumber.Value

    End If


    With student.Range("A" & iRow)

        .Offset(0, 0).Value = "=Row()-1"
        .Offset(0, 1).Value = UserForm1.Doc_number.Value
        .Offset(0, 2).Value = UserForm1.DocDate.Value
        .Offset(0, 3).Value = UserForm1.Order_Number.Value
        .Offset(0, 4).Value = UserForm1.Fleet_number.Value
        .Offset(0, 5).Value = UserForm1.Maitenance_Type.Value
        .Offset(0, 6).Value = UserForm1.ROF.Value
        .Offset(0, 7).Value = UserForm1.System_Type.Value
        .Offset(0, 8).Value = UserForm1.Asy_Type.Value
        .Offset(0, 9).Value = UserForm1.Comments.Value
        .Offset(0, 10).Value = UserForm1.OEM.Value
        .Offset(0, 11).Value = UserForm1.Part_Number.Value
        .Offset(0, 12).Value = UserForm1.SAP_Code.Value
        .Offset(0, 13).Value = UserForm1.Unit.Value
        .Offset(0, 14).Value = UserForm1.Start_Time.Value
        .Offset(0, 15).Value = UserForm1.Finish_Time.Value
        .Offset(0, 16).Value = UserForm1.Tech01.Value
        .Offset(0, 17).Value = UserForm1.Tech02.Value
        .Offset(0, 18).Value = UserForm1.Tech03.Value
        .Offset(0, 19).Value = UserForm1.Distance.Value


    End With

    Call Reset_Form

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox "Done"


    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Where is `student` defined? Also, you have a `Sub ResetItem() ` at the top. Please add `Option Explicit` at the top of the module.

Answer (score 0):

Following code assumes that student is a name of a worksheet.

```
Sub Submit_Data()
    Dim student As Worksheet
    Dim iRow As Long
    
    Set student = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("student") 'assuming sheet name is student
    
    If IsNumeric(adminpanel.txtRowNumber.Value) Then
        iRow = CLng(adminpanel.txtRowNumber.Value)
    Else
        iRow = student.Cells(student.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    End If
    
    With UserForm1
    student.Cells(iRow, 1).Formula = "=ROW() - 1"
    student.Cells(iRow, 2).Resize(1, 19).Value2 = Array( _
           .Doc_number.Value, _
           .DocDate.Value, _
           .Order_Number.Value, _
           .Fleet_number.Value, _
           .Maitenance_Type.Value, _
           .ROF.Value, _
           .System_Type.Value, _
           .Asy_Type.Value, _
           .Comments.Value, _
           .OEM.Value, _
           .Part_Number.Value, _
           .SAP_Code.Value, _
           .Unit.Value, _
           .Start_Time.Value, _
           .Finish_Time.Value, _
           .Tech01.Value, _
           .Tech02.Value, _
           .Tech03.Value, _
           .Distance.Value _
           )
    End With
    
    Call Reset_Form
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = True no need for it
    MsgBox "Done"
    
    Set student = Nothing
End Sub
```